# Map tile contains shape

Tags: .net, geometry, leaflet, geography

I am using leaflet to draw out a map which I am generating a C# MVC Controller.

My map is actually a 2D CAD drawing which consists of multiple shapes. For the sake of simplicity I am currently just focusing on lines and not factoring in zoom.

So assuming my map were zoomed to a 1:1 ratio with the drawing. For each tile I need to calculate whether or not a part of a line is within that tile. Then I need to know what the offset is and where to draw it.

I have absolutely no idea how I can calculate this? Are there any libraries or algorithms you can recommend to achieve this? I have been researching but the trail is cold.

Comment: Do you want to know, what grid cells (rectangles) are intersected by straight line?

Comment: yes.. the line can be going in any direction but is straight

Answer (score 1):

To find what tiles of rectangular grid are intersected by straight line, you can use algorithm of Woo and Amanatides described in the article ["Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm"](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~amana/research/grid.pdf). It gives cell coordinates and points of entering and leaving the cells.

[image]

Some practical implementation could be found [here](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Raytracing_Topics_Techniques-Part_4_Spatial_Subdivisions.shtml)